# publish a Visual Studio project template

Tags: .net, visual-studio, github

Lets say I have already created a proper visual studio project template and archives by following this blog [create a .net core visual studio template](https://programmingwithwolfgang.com/create-a-net-core-visual-studio-template/).

how can I then publish it so that it is added publicly to Visual Studio templates and everyone can use it?

one way is to create a Visual Studio extension, but I'm looking for an official contribution to the Visual Studio project. is there any specific GitHub repo that I can create a pull request or something to?